# Requested runtime (python-) is not available for this stack (heroku-20)

Tags: python, heroku

I am stuck trying to deploy this Flask App through Heroku. I've researched multiple ways to go about it, but can't seem a way to find it to work. This is what I get when I push to `git push heroku master`

```
remote: -----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote:  !     Requested runtime (python-) is not available for this stack (heroku-20).
remote:  !     Aborting.  More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-support
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
```

I've cleared & set up build pack and is currently:

```
=== wonders141 Buildpack URL
heroku/python
```

The runtime.txt contains:

```
python-3.9.1
```

I'm not sure why the error message doesn't define the python version, so I'm at a lost of how to go about this.

Comment: I have the same issue don't know how to solve it!

Answer (score 3):

This may be a late answer, but you have to use a newline after `python-3.9.6` in runtime.txt

Answer (score 2):

Your python version is not supported on heroku stack 20 - and make sure your python version in runtime is in lower case - see below

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the screenshot. Latest versions at https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-support#supported-runtimes

Answer (score 0):

I figured how to get past this. I had cleared everything in my requirements.txt and left only the packages I needed. Apparently a lot of unnecessary packages were included.

Comment: Can you be a little more expressive here? What is the relationship of requirements.txt to your runtime? Are you/Heroku saying some things on your list were incompatible with the stated runtime? How did you get 'unnecessary' packages on your reqs text in the first place? How did you determine which were 'unnecessary'?

Comment: I basically followed this article [here] (https://boscacci.medium.com/why-and-how-to-make-a-requirements-txt-f329c685181e). In short, I created a new virtual environment and used 'pip freeze > requirements.txt'. I can't say for sure if I was missing packages or had packages that interfered with heroku. Also, @Nahidujjaman had an answer which I can confirm. It runs even with my python-3.9.1 in runtime.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Django and I just upgrade python version to One of the supported versions in heroku, then I modified the (runtime.txt) file with the new version python-3.10.7
then I run git's commands like :

```
git status
git add -A
git commit -m "with any name you want"

git push heroku main --force
```