# My flask Heroku attempt fails, i cannot pinpoint the problem

Tags: flask, heroku

So I try to make a very simple test app to run with Heroku. Its my 3rd attempt from complete scratch. I have a single python file with very minimal content

```py
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def test():
    return "test"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

the file is named test.py, my directory also includes Procfile

```
web: gunicorn app:test
```

and requirments.txt

```
click==7.1.2
Flask==1.1.2
gunicorn==20.1.0
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.11.3
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
Werkzeug==1.0.1
```

to top it off I have gitignore to ensure IDE files do not interfere,

```
.idea
.Heroku.iml
```

and runtime.txt

```
python-3.6.0
```

I then try to create an app using

```
heroku create <appname>
```

I then use second URL it returns in the command

```
git remote add heroku <url>
```

. Afterwards I do

```
git add . 
git commit -m "some message"
git push heroku main
```

and get the following error.

```
To https://git.heroku.com/forgotten-fox.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/forgotten-fox.git'
```

I then try to do it using

```
git push heroku master
```

instead but no changes occur.
I also try to force it to use python build pack with

```
heroku buildpack:set heroku/python --app <appname>
```

as above the error it states that

```
Building on the Heroku-20 stack
remote: -----> Using buildpack: heroku/python
remote: -----> App not compatible with buildpack: https://buildpack-registry.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/python.tgz
remote:        More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure
```

I don't know how to use git mostly, but my friend advised me to create remote repository and attach it to Heroku but I was not able to find how to do the attachment.

If anyone knows what causes that and / or how to solve it i would really appreciate if you share the knowledge.

**Update:**

Thanks for pointing out wrong name for requirements file, I've renamed it. I`ve also changed my Procfile to

```
web: gunicorn test:app
```

.
Sadly it doesn't resolve the issue (yes I did commit and push the changes made).
Here is the error messages:

for `git push heroku master` :

```
Enumerating objects: 11, done.
Counting objects: 100% (11/11), done.
Delta compression using up to 6 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (9/9), done.
Writing objects: 100% (11/11), 1.66 KiB | 1.66 MiB/s, done.
Total 11 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
remote: -----> Using buildpack: heroku/python
remote: -----> App not compatible with buildpack: https://buildpack-registry.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/python.tgz
remote:        More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote:  !
remote:  ! ## Warning - The same version of this code has already been built: 36fb38193ecf8aa8d27f79682de049be81cb8807
remote:  !
remote:  ! We have detected that you have triggered a build from source code with version 36fb38193ecf8aa8d27f79682de049be81cb8807
remote:  ! at least twice. One common cause of this behavior is attempting to deploy code from a different branch.
remote:  !
remote:  ! If you are developing on a branch and deploying via git you must run:
remote:  !
remote:  !     git push heroku <branchname>:main
remote:  !
remote:  ! This article goes into details on the behavior:
remote:  !   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/duplicate-build-version
remote:
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to forgotten-fox.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/forgotten-fox.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/forgotten-fox.git'
```

and here for `git heroku push main`:

```
error: src refspec main does not match any
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/forgotten-fox.git'
```

.

**Update**
Ok, sorry everyone, I'm generally retarded. I missed the obvious part of error about build back, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65797780/requested-runtime-python-is-not-available-for-this-stack-heroku-20) it states the final fix I needed for my app to work.

Comment: `requirments.txt` must be `requirements.txt`. Is it just a misspelling in the question? If not — you need to rename the file with `git mv`, commit and push.

Comment: Note that this is not a Git issue. You're merely using Git as a mechanism for version control, with the versions (commits) going to a Heroku server to be deployed by Heroku. You have something wrong in your Heroku setup: probably the misspelled `requirements.txt` file name.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, as i mention i dont have much knowledge about git and how it all wokrs internally. Ill edit the question to remove git tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the issue is that you have to use

```
web: gunicorn test:app
```

instead of

```
web: gunicorn app:test
```

the correct format is

```
gunicorn <filename>:<app object>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, yet it doesn't seem to completely eliminate the problem. I`ve updated the question to include the outcome of trying your suggestion.